# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String JDBC MetaData

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

**My Code**

```
public static ArrayList getTablesMetadata() throws SQLException{
    String table[] = {"TABLE"};
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList tables = null;

    rs = metadata.getTables(null, null, null, table);
    tables = new ArrayList();
    while(rs.next()){
        tables.add(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }
    return tables;
}

public static void getColumnsMetadata(ArrayList tables)
        throws SQLException{
    ResultSet rs = null;

    for(String actualTable : tables){  <-----------------------------------
        rs = metadata.getColumns(null, null, actualTable, null);
        System.out.println(actualTable.toUpperCase());
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME")+ " "
                    + rs.getString("TYPE_NAME")+ " "
                    + rs.getString("COLUMN_SIZE"));
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Error is pointed out with the arrow, what im getting is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String
```

I have tried adding the  to certain parts but think im doing it wrong, or something is wrong in the code that I cant seem to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the array list type, it is assumed to hold Object.

try

```
getColumnsMetadata(ArrayList<String> tables)
```

I guess you'll also need to change:

```
tables = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and change the return value of getTablesMetadata() to

```
 ArrayList<String>
```

Comment: Well I had tried something similir to that but seems like its worked :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` uses [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Your `table` variable is a list of `Object` since the generic type was not specified. You can:

1. Cast each table object to `String`
2. Use `ArrayList<String>` instead (recommended)